# How do I restart a loop of a linked list?

Tags: c, function, loops, data-structures, linked-list

So I want to restart the loop of the linked list to print again the values, as you can see in my code if I run it I would only have a `printf` one time because it reaches the end of the list, when the second loop tries to go to the list the pointer is already at the end, how do I make it to go again to the start of the list?

```
void UC_show(L_uc_data *list, L_af_data *list1, FILE *fout)
{
    //int number_char=0;

    while (list) { // here its starts the loop of the principal list
        //Get length from names
        int n_char=strlen(list->uc_data.uc_name);
        printf("%d\n",n_char);
        fprintf(fout, "%d -> %s\n", list->uc_data.uc_number, list->uc_data.uc_name);
        while (list1) { // here it starts a loop of the secondary list
            fprintf(fout, "%d - %d - %d - %d - %d - %s\n", list1->number_uc, list1->start, list1->end, list1->done, list1->n_sessions, list1->af_name);
            list1 = list1->next;
        }
        list = list->next; // it goes to the next entry of the principal list the loop of the second list should start from the beginning
    }

}
```

Comment: You just need to save the *original value somewhere*.

Comment: Store original reference in temp variable. `L_uc_data *temp = list` and then restore your list using this. Ideally, one should iterate via temp pointer and keep initial pointer intact but yeah, you could do other way round.

Comment: Do you mind including a `main` so we can test this?

Comment: already solved the problem using @stanle input, you need more than the main to test this you need all the structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the address given into a dummy pointer. Use that pointer to iterate through your list and discard it after use! Generally a bad idea to change the value given in parameters unless it is necessary :)

Comment: do you recommend a away without a dummy pointer? i want to use the loop to search for values

Comment: The dummy pointer still point to the same address as your original one, so don't worry. You can still find your data using that pointer. Remember, a pointer is just an address, you can copy your address anywhere and it will still point you to the right place.

Comment: @RGO, stanle means something like `L_af_data *af_node = list1; while (af_node) { ...; af_node = af_node->next; }`